# How to use multiple GET action in a WebApi?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

Well I am actually trying to learn the WebApi and suppose if i have a scenario where i have two get methods like this

**CONTROLLER**

```
public class EmployeeApiController : ApiController
{
    public List<Student> GetAllStudents() { ... }

    public List<Student> EmailChange(string studentName, string Email) { ... }

    public List<Student> AddressChange(string studentName, string Address) { ... }
}

public class Student
{
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public static List<Student> students { get; set; }
}
```

I am not able to call the respective method, how can i do that, i know there are plenty of blogs but it has not helped me to understand how to really access the methods. by going through several blogs i made my entire code like this

**WebApiConfig Code**

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

**Controller Code**

```
    public List<Student> GetAllStudents()
    {
        Student.students = new List<Student> {
            new Student { StudentName="foo",Address="usa",Email="foo@yahoo.com"},
            new Student { StudentName="joe",Address="mumbai",Email="joe@yahoo.com"},
            new Student { StudentName="albert",Address="georgia",Email="albert@yahoo.com"},
            new Student { StudentName="prince",Address="missisipi",Email="prince@yahoo.com"}
        };
        return Student.students;
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public List<Student> UpdateEmail(string studentName, string Email)
    {
        return Student.students.Select(i =>
        {
            if (i.StudentName == studentName)
            {
                i.Email = Email;
            }
            return i;
        }).ToList();

    }
    [HttpGet]
    public List<Student> UpdateAddress(string studentName, string Address)
    {
        return Student.students.Select(x =>
        {
            if (x.StudentName == studentName)
            {
                x.Address = Address;
            }
            return x;
        }).ToList();
    }
}

public class Student
{
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public static List<Student> students { get; set; }
}
```

I am little confused on how to access both the `UpdateEmai`l method and the `UpdateAddress` method using the GET request.

**UPDATE 1**

When i make a call like this

`http://localhost:53711/api/EmployeeApi/UpdateAddress` or

`http://localhost:53711/api/EmployeeApi/UpdateEmail`

i get an error like this

[image]

and when i make a call like this i get an error like

http://localhost:53711/api/EmployeeApi/UpdateEmail/foo/foo
[image]

Comment: add the routes you use for calls.

Comment: @LijinJohn You are correct I misread the error message. The issue is that none of the actions you showed match the url entered.

Comment: @Nkosi please do you know the solution, actually i am scratching my head about this issue for quiet a long time you see

Comment: given that you have `{id}` parameter in url template and you enter `foo` in the url, yet have no matching parameter in any of the action, the route could not be matched. what exactly was `foo` suppose to populate?

Comment: Also, the naming convention used for your actions are misleading. you are doing GETs yet the actions have Update in the name. which usually implies POST or PUT methods

Comment: @Nkosi please see the method in the above question, i tried all the options but couldnt get the result, actually i have pasted all the code in the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132646/discussion-between-lijin-john-and-nkosi).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Either change template to `routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{studentName}"`, and leave methods as it

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) {
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{studentName}"
    );
}
```

**OR**

leave template as is, ie: `"api/{controller}/{action}/{id}"` and change method parameter to `(string id,.......)`

```
[HttpGet]
public List<Student> UpdateEmail(string id, string Email) { ... }
```

**OR**

You could also forego convention-based routing and use attribute routing

```
[RoutePrefix("api/EmployeeApi")]
public class EmployeeApiController : ApiController
{
    //GET api/EmployeeApi
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    public List<Student> GetAllStudents() { ... }

    //GET api/EmployeeApi/EmailChange/foo/foo@email.com
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("EmailChange/{studentName}/{email}")]
    public List<Student> EmailChange(string studentName, string email) { ... }

    //GET api/EmployeeApi/AddressChange/foo/China
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("AddressChange/{studentName}/{address}")]
    public List<Student> AddressChange(string studentName, string Address) { ... }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for all your labour to take time and explain me the working of webApi

Answer (score 2):

your `WebApConig.cs` should look like the following -

```
api/{controller}/{action}/{id}
```

then issue calls like -

```
http://localhost:port/api/Ctrl/action
```

Comment: please see my update for the answer you have given, thanks